# Facebook SDK - FBSession: No AppID provided

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, xcode6

I want to integrate with Facebook login SDK in my iOS project. The problem is I got this error message during launching the app.

```
2015-01-08 18:33:06.591 XXXXX[24994:2533100] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: No AppID provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'
```

I already include this line into my `info.plist` but it is still not working.

info.list

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>&lt;1025024xxxxxxxx&gt;</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>XXXXXX</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb&lt;1025024xxxxxxxx&gt;</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

I suspect it has not detected my Facebook ID. I'm using Xcode6.1.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is two `info.plist` file in your project with same name. one folder for `YourProjectTests` in which `info.plist` file and other `YourProject` is also `info.plist` file.

**Two plist file :**

[image]

You have to set your `FacebookAppID` in `YourProject` info.plist file, but not set `YourProjectTests` info.plist

This error is occurs because of  `YourProjectTests` in which `info.plist` file setting `FacebookAppID`

Add Your `FacebookAppID` inabove `info.plist` file as above image.

Otherwise set also `FacebookAppID` as below.

[image]

Comment: Yes! In my case, somehow my XCTests Info.plist was where I thought my main project's should have been.

Answer (score 1):

if you have already added App ID in info.plist and getting crash then make sure you have added this single line code in AppDelegate Class  didFinishLaunchingOption

```
//Facebook setup
    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```